# Java Spring-boot and in memory db H2. db not in h2 web console

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2, in-memory-database

This is my embedded database:

```
   public void init() {
      EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
      db = builder
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .addScript("h2/create.sql")
            .addScript("h2/insert.sql")
            .build();
    }
```

When I launch JUnit tests, I don't see in web console, the db that was created during application context intialization.

```
@Before
public void initTest() throws SQLException {
    Server webServer = Server.createWebServer("-web", "-webAllowOthers", "-webPort", "8082");
    webServer.start();
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Did you try this? spring.h2.console.enabled=true

Answer (score 1):

Please refer: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-sql-h2-console

You might want to use the following properties:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/path/to/console
```

Or start server programmatically:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean h2servletRegistration() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new WebServlet());
    registration.addUrlMappings("/console/*");
    registration.addInitParameter("webAllowOthers", "true");
    return registration;
}
```